# Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550 Sender address has null MX

Tags: laravel, smtp

P.S. I am doing all of this testing on my local machine.I have tested my smtp settings with this online website https://www.smtper.net/. Each one of below services are sending the emails.

I am trying to setup email confirmation system for my Laravel application and keep on getting this error with email created through cpanel.

I have tried using Gmail/mailtrap/mailosaur for testing with these settings and everything was working fine:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=ab723b95067210
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailosaur.net
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=hgyqqqgn@mailosaur.net
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

but now when I am using my custom email i am getting this error in my logs file:

[2021-12-26 09:17:53] local.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 Sender address has null MX
" {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 550): Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 Sender address has null MX

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.ionos.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@domain.co.uk
MAIL_PASSWORD='password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.co.uk
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

"mailbox unavailable 550 Sender address has null MX".

It seems your smtp server can't find the IP address of the receiving mail server.
Are you sending to a valid email address?
Have you set up a DNS MX record?

Comment: I am sending to valid email address and I have added DNS MX record.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working well on my environment. Please try like this.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=<your_username_goes_here>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your_password_goes_here>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=<your_email_goes_here>
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"`
```

Comment: Mailtrap is working fine. I want to use business email address noreply@domain.com which is causing problems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the sender email is valid. By that I mean if the provider of your sender email exist.

> Example of invalide email: user@exemple.com